# Android widget talk to service and service talk to widget

Tags: java, android, widget

I have an Android app whose `service` is started when app starts and when app is killed, `service` is also destroyed.
I have a `home screen widget` starting alongside with app. It has 3 imageviews - "Play","Next","Previous". 
On press of any of these `imageview` in widget, they need to talk  to `service` and `service` talks to library etc.
When `service` has an answer, it responds to widget with status OK or NO. Based on the response, I need to update the `imageviews`.

When the app is killed, I need to gray out my widget fully. In this situation, when I click on the greyed out widget, I need to start the app. Could anyone help me please
how I could achieve this.

Here is my widget code -

```
 public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private Intent serviceIntent;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName componentName;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        componentName = new ComponentName(context, ControlScreenWidgetProvider.class);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.PLAY,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "PLAY",componentName));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.NEXT,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "NEXT",componentName));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.PREVIOUS,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "PREVIOUS",componentName));

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName componentName;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        componentName = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

        if ("PLAY".equals(intent.getAction())) {

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.PLAY,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "PLAY",componentName));
            // Dont know what to do here

        }
        else if ("NEXT".equals(intent.getAction())) {

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.lock_door,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "NEXT",componentName));
            // Dont know what to do here

        }
        else if ("PREVIOUS".equals(intent.getAction())) {

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.lock_door,getPendingSelfIntent(context, "PREVIOUS",componentName));
            // Dont know what to do here

        }
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action, ComponentName componentName) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, componentName);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use sticky broadcast receivers

Comment: can you please give me an example or some idea of how should i do it ? Currently  I dont know how to do this in service. Bear me, I am new to widget development